# Debug function altough macros disabled

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was given a template for report (.dotm) with alot of vba code behind that gets data from a mssql database and writes the data at some bookmarks.
Unfortunately, the code has an error and I have to fix it.

Since I have never done vba before, I'm a bit lost.
There is a function with 2 parameters that does everything.

Can you tell me how I can debug this function?
I have set a breakpoint to the first line but how can I tell word(?) to execute the function?

My first approach was to add a button and set the onclick event to this function. But unfortunately macros are disabled by our policy and this doesn't work :(

Can you please help me out how I can get inside this function?

Comment: Well, you're asking how to drive a car without turning it on. Ask your sys admin to grant you rights or I don't think you will never debug a macro if they are disabled.

Comment: How can anyone expect the code in the template to work if macros are disabled? That said, try **ALT+F11** to get into the VBA environment and show the code. Put the cursor in the code you want to debug and press **F8** to step into it or **F5** to run it to any breakpoint. (If the code you want to debug has parameters, you have to write a dummy Sub to call the function with test-parameters first and step into that Sub).

Comment: Check in your trust center settings to see if you have macros disabled. If so then enable them

Comment: @OlleSjögren: Thanks for this tip! When I do this, I get the "The macros in this project are disabled"-errormessage but I know now how I can get to a defined breakpoint if macros were enabled. You can add this as answer so  I can accept it if you want :-) thanks!

Comment: @Sam: Thanks I already checked it and I cannot modify these settings.. they're forced by our group policies I guess

Comment: Then why do you need find the error if the code cannot be run even if you fix it? Can anyone run it?

Comment: @OlleSjögren that's a great question.. we just have to fix it, we're magicians you know? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can anyone expect the code in the template to work if macros are disabled?

Try <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to get into the VBA environment and show the code. Put the cursor in the code you want to debug and press <kbd>F8</kbd> to step into it or <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it to any breakpoint.. If the code you want to debug has parameters, you have to write a dummy `Sub` to call the function with test-parameters.

Also, see sams comment about the trust center. Maybe you can change the settings yourself to allow macros.